# How to reset Mac Catalina password!

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, catalina, password

I will admit that i was messing around deleting system files, and deleted bunch of files,system asked permission.

In a stage I wanted to delete something entered password, didn't accept. Well here the panic started. I changed the password from setting and also not accepting the password. I restarted the mac then im stuck at the login page, Even after resetting password in recovery mode the recently changed password not accepted.
I've tried resetting it by Apple Id and same thing not accepted.
[image: password reset phase]

Comment: If you can get to regular Recovery, try installing the OS again. Done from Recovery [not Internet Recovery] it will simply re-lay the OS without affecting your data. It's worth a shot before blowing it all out of the water & starting over.

Comment: What do you think about the internet re install ?

Comment: I've never tried it, idk whether it will do a repair install or a complete nuke & pave.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are at the point of completely reinstalling a fresh system and provide fresh passwords.

It may keep user data, but if not then you will need your backup.

Next time around you should have an admin account and a user account, so you are less likely to delete things you should not.

Comment: Do you have any solution rather than re-installing, such as command lines in single user (cmd+s)?.     only way is to backup my data in disk utilities connecting an external hard drive?

Comment: well, you could use another mac to "read" the problem one like a hard drive. But I was assuming that you had a current backup, you might find that you cannot get the data from the faulty machine.

Comment: Actually I've rescued the documents file into a usb as .dmg. do you think will work with the other files? Hoping...

Comment: So test that dmg and find out.

Comment: I've applied this advice to create a new user [ Enter the following command, exactly as shown. Substitute "startup disk" with the actual name of your startup disk.
rm '/Volumes/Macintosh HD/var/db/.AppleSetupDone' made my macbook air boot in circles ??

Comment: I don't follow what you tried to achieve with that. Just do a full system install and follow the normal steps.